# The pygame set_at function doesn't seem to work correctly. Can somebody explain it's behavior and help me work around it?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to edit a png file pixel by pixel using python's pygame library.  Here's the basic process: I load the png and loop through all the pixels.  The loop passes the rgb values of the current pixel to a function that finds the closest euclidean distance match to a predefined set of rgb values (a palette if you will). Then I change the pixels color to that returned by the matching function using the surface.set_at() function.

I've been struggling to determine why the results simply aren't what I expect. Eventually I noticed this.

```
>>> image.set_at((0,0),(160, 130, 95, 255))
>>> image.get_at((0,0))
(152, 128, 96, 255)
```

It's pretty clear to see that the set_at() function does some type of rounding to the passed color.  This is a problem for me so I have two questions.

> 1) Why is the set_at() function making this change?
>
> 2) How can I work around this and explicitly set the rgb value to what I want?

Thanks all.

Comment: Note to moderators: I wanted to add the set_at tag but was unable to.  It was automatically changed to the "set" and "at-command" tags.

Comment: I don't think a 'set_at' tag would be useful. Btw: What color depth is your surface? Are you using a color palette?

Comment: I'm admittedly very new to all of this (python, pygame, and color manipulation) so I'm not entirely sure how to answer your questions.  I haven't explicitly set a color palette.  Perhaps there is a default palette in use?  As for the color depth, the rgba values are 8 bits each.  Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, this is based on reading the docs, not on practical experience.

From http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load

> The returned Surface will contain the same color format, colorkey and alpha transparency as the file it came from. You will often want to call Surface.convert - change the pixel format of an image with no arguments, to create a copy that will draw more quickly on the screen.

Perhaps try something like this before your code...

```
converted_image = image.convert_alpha()
```

Comment: Woot!  I just tried attempted this though I accidentally used image.convert() instead of image.convert_alpha().  Regardless this solved my problem perfectly.  Thanks for the help!